# python packages are not being installed

Tags: windows-10, python, anaconda

I have tried to install new python libraries but it is not being installed. I have uninstalled python and reinstalled it but it didn't work.  The image shows the error occurred while installing:

[image: the image shows the error occurred while installing]

Answer (score 0):

Try to install with pip command and if it fails then 
see the answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33699577/conda-update-failed-ssl-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-ver

And this answer to add your own SSL certificate

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356413/how-to-add-a-custom-ca-root-certificate-to-the-ca-store-used-by-pip-in-windows/52961564#52961564

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.